# Where to see list of community wiki question ticked by me?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Can anyone help me to see question list that were made community wiki by me?

Comment: Tempted to edit to *Where to see list of community wiki questions which have ticked me off*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the search engine and type:

```
user:<your_id> wiki:yes
```

I see in your case two results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A928786+wiki%3Ayes

If you just want answers, do

```
user:928786 is:answer wiki:yes
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A928786+wiki%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer

Answer (score 4):

`were made community wiki by me?`

You can use this [data.se  query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/124006/posts-made-wiki-by-me)

```
SELECT
   ph.PostID [Post Link]
FROM PostHistory ph
  WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 16 -- Wiki
  AND ph.UserID = ##UserID##
```

We need to do this since `wiki:yes` search option includes any wiki post that you participated not just the ones made wiki by you